# Rails: Add value to collection_select from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I need to be able to add a new value to my collection_select if the options available do not include this value, however, the value will need to be a new record created in a different model.

I have a Task model where one can create new tasks for which each has a person who is responsible to complete the task:

```
    class Task < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :project
      belongs_to :person
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

The Person model looks like this:

```
      class Person < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :company
        has_many :tasks
        belongs_to :user
      end
```

In my tasks view, I have code for selecting the person responsible for the task using a collection_select:

```
    <%= f.collection_select :person_id , current_user.people.order(:last_name), :id, :last_name, {prompt: "Select a person"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

Let's say that in my collection_select I have 1) John and 2) Peter but I need to assign the task for Jane, at the moment I need to leave the Task form and go to the Person form, add Jane as a new person and then go back and create the new Task record.

What I want to do make it easier to use.  I would hope that I could add an option in the collection_select dropdown (e.g. "Add new person") which when selected uses some AJAX or other magic to take me straight to the new person form (either as a popup screen or nested form) and once I add Jane as a new record it goes back to the task form.

Is this possible?

Comment: that's possible but you should use select2 you can learn from this site: https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails

Comment: I can see how this makes the select searchable but will have to dig deeper to understand how it can allow me to add options by creating new records in the Person model.